# Winsock ~ Creating an UDP Listener (Multiple vs 1 socket)

Tags: c++, networking, udp, winsock, winsock2

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I am researching networking a bit and I decided I'd like to create a small and simple networking library with Winsock. (I am using Completion Ports and Overlapped IO though)

As I researched a bit I came to the following steps for a TCP Listener(Correct me if I am wrong):

1. Create a Listening Socket
2. Bind it to a port/IP
3. Listen on it
4. When a new connection is created, give a seperate Socket for that connection.
5. Listener continue's to listen, the specific connection is handled as needed.

EDIT: With a 'connection' from here I mean communication between the server and distinct clients.

Though for an UDP Listener we need to make use of WSARecvFrom which returns the IP address at the lpFrom parameter. Now I was wondering the following:

Is it better to make one UDP Socket listen to incoming connections on a specific port with WSARecvFrom and create new sockets for every specific connection? Or could I just use the UDP Socket itself with WSASendTo. Would that cause any performance penalties if one UDP Socket is used for for example 1000 connections? Or would it be the same or even better then creating/duplicating seperate Sockets for each different incoming connection?

Note: If multiple sockets are needed how would you handle sockets listening on the same port or could a client accept UDP from different ports?

Hope you guys can help!

Ps. Extra tips are always welcome!

Comment: You need to rephrase your questions since there is no "connection" when using UDP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike TCP, UDP is connection-less, and as such you don't need to create separate sockets for each party.  One UDP socket can handle everything.  Bind it to a local IP/Port and call `WSARecvFrom()` once, and when it reports data to your IOCP you can process the data as needed (if another thread if needed) and then call `WSARecvFrom()` again.  Each time new data arrives, you have to look at the reported `lpFrom` address to know the IP/Port of the sender.  And yes, you can use the same UDP socket for sending data to each sender when needed.

Comment: This exactly the answer I was looking for! A small follow up though: Is it also advised to use only one UDP socket to save resources? Or would it be better to use multiple even if one would be possible? Thanks!

Comment: A benefit to using multiple UDP sockets is if you want to use `connect()` to "lock down" the IP/Port pairs for a specific party per socket, then you can use `WSARecv()` and `WSASend()` instead of `WSARecvFrom()` and `WSASendTo()` and not have to exchange IP/Port information each time, filtering packets so a socket exchanges packets only with the peer IP/Port it is "connected" to, just like with TCP. But that has limited uses and most UDP protocols don't really need it. So it is a personal choice whether to use multiple single-use sockets, or a single multiple-use socket.

Comment: (I promise to not ask more after this!) When I connect() an UDP socket to a specific IP/Port will only that socket receive the packets to that port? Or will an UDP socket calling RecvFrom() also possibly get those packages? Hope you can help me one last time!

Comment: When you `connect()` a UDP socket, all it does is associates a specific remote IP/Port with that socket so it will receive packets only from that IP/Port. If more than one UDP socket are bound to the same receiving port (which requires `SO_REUSEADDR` to accomplish), it is a race condition which socket will receive a given packet if any of the sockets are not "connected" to a specific remote IP/Port.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying! You helped me a lot:P